# Add a timestamp to svnadmin

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Is it possible to make a `svnadmin dump` command where you display the start and stop time of the command?

I have searched around for it, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Why don't you just make a script in which you print current system time before and after the svn command?

Comment: Or something like this: date && svnadmin dump && date

Answer (score 0):

Just run something like this before and after running the task:

```
echo svnadmin dump started %DATE% %TIME%
svnadmin dump FOO > MyBackupFile.bak
echo svndamin dump finished %DATE% %TIME%
```

You could also check for the exit code to catch errors should any occur.